# conditional statements are not getting evaluated inside Makefile function

Tags: function, makefile, conditional-statements

I have a function in a Makefile where I am trying to evaluate input parameters in ifeq statements like below:

```
define set_target_dts
    ifeq ($(1),virgo)
        @echo "Building for Virgo"
        ifeq ($(2),soc_prototype)
            @echo "Building for soc prototype"
            DTS_FILE_NAME := virgo_soc_proto.dts
        else
            @echo "Building for soc"
            DTS_FILE_NAME := virgo.dts
        endif
    else ifeq ($(1),gemini)
        @echo "Building for Gemini"
        ifeq ($(2),soc_prototype)
            DTS_FILE_NAME := gemini_soc_proto.dts
        else
            DTS_FILE_NAME := gemini.dts
        endif
    else        
        $(info Selected Target is:$(1) $(2))
        $(error Please select the correct target...)
    endif
endef
```

Whenever I call this function using

`$(call set_target_dts,virgo,soc_prototype)`

It is throwing me this error:

```
Selected Target is:virgo soc
Makefile:48: *** Please select the correct target....  Stop.
```

Which means that neither the ifeq is evaluated correctly, nor the second parameter value is correctly retreived.

Please guide me about my mistakes. I have never made Makefile functions before.

Comment: Please show the invocation of the function (the `$(call...)`) in actual context.  Is it sitting outside of any rule, as it appears to be here?  Or is it used in a recipe?  Or...?  In makefiles, context is critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the outset I'll set aside your secondary problem:

> nor the second parameter value is correctly retreived.

This is not reproduced for me when I run a make calling

```
$(call set_target_dts,virgo,soc_prototype)
```

with the definition of `set_target_dts` that you have posted. I get:

```
Selected Target is:virgo soc_prototype
Makefile:24: *** Please select the correct target.... Stop.
```

as it should be, not:

```
Selected Target is:virgo soc
Makefile:48: *** Please select the correct target....  Stop.
```

as you did. I think something not very make-related is amiss there.

**And so onward**

You are misapprehending how `define`-ed variables are expanded and how
function calls are expanded. A "user defined function"
in GNU Make is conventionally a variable with a multi-line definition enclosed by `define varname`  and `endef`, with deferred expansion of the enclosed body so that arguments can be substituted for `$(n)` parameters in that body when the the function-call construction `$(func,args,...)` is
expanded<sup>1</sup>. `make` does not recognise any "logic" in the body of a variable definition while expanding it. (Although `make` might recognize such logic later if `make` itself *uses* the expansion).

First you should carefully read the [GNU Make manual: 3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#).
Having grasped the distinction between *immediate* and *deferred* expansion,
note that the schema that fits your definition of `set_target_dts` is:

```
define *immediate*
  *deferred*
endef
```

The expansion of the definition body is deferred until the variable is used - e.g. by
function-call expansion `$(call foo,args...)`. That is the right choice. You will see from the documentation
that you could in theory adapt your definition to, say, the schema:

```
define *immediate* :=
  *immediate*
endef
```

But if you did that then the definition would not be viable for
functions calls, because the definition would be frozen with all  `$(n)`
parameters empty. Deferred expansion is necessary to give you a chance to
supply `args...`.

With that in mind a worked example will best clarify what you've
observed, and what's misconceived about the definition of `set_target_dts`.
Consider this makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
define foo
    ifeq (1,0)
        $(info In condition 1 = 0)
        $(error In condition 1 = 0)
    else
        $(info In condition 1 ~= 0)
        $(info $$(1) = [$(1)])
        echo "Parameter $$(1) = [$(1)]"
    endif
endef

$(info $$(foo,bar) = <<<$(call foo,bar)>>>)

all:
```

Let's just run it:

```
$ make
In condition 1 = 0
Makefile:12: *** In condition 1 = 0. Stop.
```

Observe: the fact that the `$(error ...)` call was within the scope of the unsatisfiable
condition `ifeq (1,0)` didn't stop the the `$(error ...)` call from being
fatally executed.

Let's remove the error call so we can get further. I'll also label the lines
within the definition of `foo` so I can talk through them:

```
$ cat Makefile
define foo
    ifeq (1,0) # A
        $(info In condition 1 = 0) # B
    else # C    
        $(info In condition 1 ~= 0) # D
        $(info $$(1) = [$(1)]) # E
        echo "Parameter $$(1) = [$(1)]" # F
    endif # G
endef

$(info $$(foo,bar) = <<<$(call foo,bar)>>>)

all:
```

We know that all the labelled lines fall into deferred expansion. In our Makefile,
that will happen in:

```
<<<$(call foo,bar)>>>
```

(It will not happen in `$$(foo,bar)`, because that expression is escaped.)

In performing the expansion of the definition, `make` works like so:

- Any un-escaped parameter `$(n)` is replaced with the `n`th argument, if any, otherwise the empty string.
- Any un-escaped `$(name[...])` construct is expanded.
- Any escaped construct `$$...` is expanded to `$...`
- Any text that is not in the scope of `$` goes through unchanged.

So here is what will happen, line by line, as `make` expands `$(call foo,bar)`:

- Line **A**: There are no `$`s here. Add it unchanged to the expansion.
- Line **B**: Expand the `$(info ...)` call *now*. That action prints `...` to the standard output *now*
  and returns the empty string. Add that empty string to the expansion.
- Line **C**: Same as Line **A**.
- Line **D**: Same as Line **B**
- Line **E**: Same as Line **B**
- Line **F**: The escaped `$$(1)` is replaced with literal `$(1)`. The un-escaped `$(1)`
  in replaced with `bar`. The resulting line is added to the expansion.
- Line **F**: Same as Line **A**.

Thus the final expansion of `$(call foo,bar)` is:

```
    ifeq (1,0) # A
         # B
    else # C    
         # D
         # E
        echo "Parameter $(1) = [bar]" # F
    endif # G
```

Let's confirm that by running the amended Makefile:

```
$ make
In condition 1 = 0
In condition 1 ~= 0
$(1) = [bar]
$(foo,bar) = <<<    ifeq (1,0) # A
         # B
    else # C    
         # D
         # E
        echo "Parameter $(1) = [bar]" # F
    endif # G>>>
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Note that the expansion of:

```
$(info In condition 1 = 0) # B  => prints "In condition 1 = 0"
```

was uninhibited by apparently being in the scope of the unsatisfiable
condition `ifeq (1,0)` and that *in the expanded definition* it
does not even appear to be that scope: the only text in that scope
is `<empty_string># B`.

By analogy you should now see why the `$(error ...)` call that
we removed was executed despite lying "within the scope" of `ifeq (1,0)`.
In the context of expanding the definition of `foo`, that condition is
merely *some text* that requires no expansion itself and is just
added to the expansion of the function call. The `$(error ...)` call is some
more text that *does* require expansion, and doing that immediately terminates
`make` with failure.

And in that light you can see that in your own case,

```
$(call set_target_dts,virgo,soc_prototype)
```

will execute:

```
$(info Selected Target is:$(1) $(2))
```

and also:

```
$(error Please select the correct target...)
```

regardless of any surrounding conditional "make-logic", because in the
context of expanding the function call `make` does not care what the
surrounding text is: it isn't doing any make-logic here.

**But...**

If you intend to call your function in the context of a *recipe*,
then it certainly does matter what the text of the expansion is,
since recipes are executed by the shell. And
since your definition of `set_target_dts` contains shell commands (`echo`) you evidently intend to use it that way. Our makefiles so far
have also contained an `echo` command to hint at the same intention.

Let's make a final revision of our Makefile to check that out:

```
$ cat Makefile
define foo
    ifeq (1,0) # A
        $(info In condition 1 = 0) # B
    else # C    
        $(info In condition 1 ~= 0) # D
        $(info $$(1) = [$(1)]) # E
        echo "Parameter $$(1) = [$(1)]" # F
    endif # G
endef

$(info $$(foo,bar) = <<<$(call foo,bar)>>>)

all:
    @echo "Building all"
    $(call foo,bar)
    
$ make
In condition 1 = 0
In condition 1 ~= 0
$(1) = [bar]
$(foo,bar) = <<<    ifeq (1,0) # A
         # B
    else # C    
         # D
         # E
        echo "Parameter $(1) = [bar]" # F
    endif # G>>>
In condition 1 = 0
In condition 1 ~= 0
$(1) = [bar]
Building all
ifeq (1,0) # A
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [Makefile:15: all] Error 2
```

See here that the `$(call foo,bar)` within the recipe for target `all`, just like the the previous previous one in `<<<$(call foo,bar)>>>`,
is expanded *before* execution of the recipe (before "Building all"). It
would have to be, wouldn't it?

Then the expansion is given to the shell to execute and of course,
the shell chokes on line **A**: `ifeq (1,0)` does not make sense to the shell.

If the definition of `set_target_dts` is meant to be such that,
after functional expansion with arguments, a shell command or expression will result
then you must write that definition in such a way that, after expansion, you get nothing
but a shell command or expression. Make-logic will not "do its job and vanish" in the
context of a variable definition expansion destined for recipe execution. It will
not do its job, and it will not vanish.

---

1 @MadScientist correctly commented: "Just to note, a user-defined function in make doesn't have to be multiline or created with define. Any macro can be used with $(call ...). Generally any macro that refers to at least one variable (e.g., $1, $2) is a user-defined function. You could even have zero arguments but it only makes sense to use n-ary macros where n > 0: $(call foo) is legal but is the same thing as just $(foo)."

Comment: Just to note, a user-defined function in make doesn't have to be multiline or created with `define`.  Any macro can be used with `$(call ...)`.  Generally any macro that refers to at least one variable (e.g., `$1`, `$2`) is a user-defined function.  You could even have zero arguments but it only makes sense to use n-ary macros where n > 0: `$(call foo)` is legal but is the same thing as just `$(foo)`.

Comment: As a final comment I'll say that if you want to use make preprocessor operations like `ifeq` etc. that are kept in a variable you have to do it in the context of an `$(eval ...)` function.  But note that as you point out you need to "hide" the functions that would expanded by `$(call ...)` so they are not expanded until `$(eval ...)`, so `$$(error foo)` etc.  Personally I think this is all too complex and I'm sure there are simpler ways to do whatever the OP wants to do, but unfortunately they didn't describe the requirements just the failed attempt.

Comment: @MadScientist Noted - included your 1st comment in a footnote to the post.

Answer (score 0):

> conditional statements are not getting evaluated inside Makefile function

Sort of.  Conditional statements are parsed and acted on *immediately*, as the makefile is being parsed.  Any that appear within the body of a function therefore control the actual definition of the function, based on evaluation of their condition while the function definition is being parsed.  They have already had all the effect they ever will before any calls to the function can be expanded.

> Which means that neither the ifeq is evaluated correctly, nor the second parameter value is correctly retreived.

No, it means that `ifeq` works differently than you thought.  More generally, GNU `make` *functions* work differently than you probably think.  `make`'s is not a scripting language.  Makefiles are not scripts. `make` rules are not functions, and neither are GNU `make` "functions", really.  `make` functions -- especially user-defined ones -- are better characterized as parameterized *macros*.

In particular, ...

> a function in a Makefile [that] evaluate[s] input parameters in ifeq statements

... is not possible in GNU `make`.

Do not attempt to write makefiles as if they were scripts.  You will end up with non-idiomatic makefiles, often with serious problems.  In particular, I feel comfortable recommending that you not use user-defined functions *at all*, as I have never found the need myself, and the idea of "functions" tends to put a person in the wrong head space.

Insufficient information is presented in the question to recommend what you should do instead in your case, but guessing based on the form of the function, I imagine that either creating multiple rules where you are now trying to use one or performing some kind of expansion based on target names might serve.

Comment: I did not need to use functions, rather target only. I used the make specific conditionals $(if $(filter...)...) etc to make it work..